# How to cross compile kernel driver on iMX6S?

Tags: c, linux, cross-compiling, kernel-module

I'm using iMX6S-EVK ARMV7 with kernel version 4.9.88. I'm writing some simple kernel driver. I also download kernel linux 4.9.88. But when I compile, I got this error:

```
ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid. include/generated/autoconf.h
or include/config/auto.conf are missing. Run 'make oldconfig && make
prepare' on kernel src to fix it. WARNING: Symbol version dump
./Module.symvers is missing; modules will have no dependencies and
modversions.

CC [M]
/home/user1/Desktop/exploringBB/extras/kernel/gpio_test/gpio_test.o
In file included from <command-line>:0:0:
././include/linux/kconfig.h:4:32: fatal error: generated/autoconf.h:
No such file or directory compilation terminated.
```

This is my Makefile:

```make
KERNEL ?= /home/user1/Desktop/linux 
ARCH ?= arm 
CROSS_COMPILE ?= arm-linux-gnueabihf- 
obj-m+=hello.o
all: 
make ARCH=$(ARCH) CROSS_COMPILE=$(CROSS_COMPILE) -C $(KERNEL) M=$(PWD) modules 
clean: 
make ARCH=$(ARCH) CROSS_COMPILE=$(CROSS_COMPILE) -C $(KERNEL) M=$(PWD) clean
```

I execute this command to build:

```sh
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf-
```

Did I missing something? What should I do now?

Comment: For build a module against a Linux kernel, you need to **build** that **Linux kernel** first, with the same `ARCH` and `CROSS_COMPILE` settings as you want to apply for your module.That is, firstly run `make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf-` for the Linux kernel itself (in the Linux kernel directory), then run the same command for your driver (in the directory with your driver).

Comment: Hi @Tsyvarev, thank you for your answer. I'm building Linux kernel as your guide and it seems like taking a long time. I will response as soon as it's done.

Comment: It's notice that I missing .config file and suggest me that run make menuconfig or make oldconfig. Then I did "make menuconfig". Then I got this error:
`In function ‘xfs_check_ondisk_structs’,
    inlined from ‘init_xfs_fs’ at fs/xfs/xfs_super.c:1966:2:
./include/linux/compiler.h:518:38: error: call to ‘__compiletime_assert_119’ declared with attribute error: XFS: sizeof(xfs_dir2_sf_entry_t) is wrong, expected 3`

Comment: I tried to generate .config by other way. It's using defconfig file. And It's working now. But when I switch to build kernel module. I still got error. 
`/home/user1/Desktop/kernel/gpio_test/gpio_test.mod.c:8:1: error: variable ‘__this_module’ has initializer but incomplete type
 __attribute__((section(".gnu.linkonce.this_module"))) = {
 ^
/home/user1/Desktop/kernel/gpio_test/gpio_test.mod.c:9:2: error: unknown field ‘name’ specified in initializer
  .name = KBUILD_MODNAME,`

Comment: And: 
`/home/user1/Desktop//kernel/gpio_test/gpio_test.mod.c:14:2: error: unknown field ‘arch’ specified in initializer
  .arch = MODULE_ARCH_INIT,
  ^
/home/user1/Desktop//kernel/gpio_test/gpio_test.mod.c:14:10: error: ‘MODULE_ARCH_INIT’ undeclared here (not in a function)
  .arch = MODULE_ARCH_INIT,
/home/user1/Desktop/kernel/gpio_test/gpio_test.mod.c:10:2: error: unknown field ‘init’ specified in initializer
  .init = init_module,`

Comment: It seems your kernel is configured without the modules support. See e.g. that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57002979/lime-kernel-module-cross-compilation-fails. Hint for the future: When you get an error message, it has a high chance that googling for it it would reveal useful information about the possible solutions.